# Join MySQL table on regexp (after underscore)

Tags: mysql, regex, join

So what I try to achieve is to join two tables where the columns to join needs a regexp to match both tables together. I used to have a solution with LIKE (%) that worked but now I want to try make the query faster by just matching with regexp.

```
table1
|   col1     |    col2    |
|   blablaaa |12323_string|

table2
|   col2     |    col2    |
|   blabla   |   string   |
```

So the strings on col2 is where I want to join them but I need to match the string after the underscore...

*this is the closest I got and I still might be way off*

```
SELECT *
FROM table1 AS t1 JOIN table2 AS t2 
ON t1.col2 REGEXP CONCAT('(?<=_)[^_] + t2.col2')
```

I dont know if there is a warm soul out there who could help me with this.

Comment: This is a bad implementation that breaks first normal form.  It won't perform well.  You should reconsider this if you can.

Comment: Yes I kind of know that, I was hoping on a temporary solution. I want to reconsider it but I dont know how to start tackling the basics. I guess reading up on database design would be one option... =) any quick pointers?

Answer (score 1):

Just use `substring_index()`:

```
SELECT *
FROM table1 t1 JOIN
     table2 t2 
     ON t2.col2 = substring_index(t1.col2, '_', -1);
```

Or perhaps `like`:

```
SELECT *
FROM table1 t1 JOIN
     table2 t2 
     ON t1.col2 LIKE CONCAT('%\_', t2.col2);
```

Comment: Thanks both worked but it did´nt make my querying any faster :) But I learnt a lot from the two methods and it will help me in the future so thanks!

Comment: @MichaelScottJR . . . an index on `table1(col2)` might help the second query.  On `table2(col2)` might help the first.